# Initialize a dataframe from a known list of dimensions defined by vectors

Tags: r, initialization

I am trying to initialize a dataframe based on size and dimensionality defined by vector indices:
for example -

```
ind1 <- c('red', 'blue')
ind2 <- c('circle', 'square', 'triangle')
```

`myFun(ind1,ind2) # this is the great function that yields your result:`

```
red circle
red square
red triangle
blue circle
blue square
blue triangle
```

Comment: Perfect, this performs wonderfully. If you make this into an answer I will mark it correct!

Comment: @Psidom make it as an answer dude :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `expand.grid` which *creates a data frame from all combinations of the input vectors*:

```
expand.grid(ind1, ind2)

#  Var1     Var2
#1  red   circle
#2 blue   circle
#3  red   square
#4 blue   square
#5  red triangle
#6 blue triangle
```

---

Also if you use `data.table` you can use *Cross Join* `CJ`:

```
data.table::CJ(ind1, ind2)

#     V1       V2
#1: blue   circle
#2: blue   square
#3: blue triangle
#4:  red   circle
#5:  red   square
#6:  red triangle
```